# Login page in selenium not firing

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Team,
I am stuck in one issue.
I have two classes One where i have created a plain login functionality using constructor and in second one i am instantiating the login.
The issue is the test case is terminating immediately.
Please help me out
I am giving the below code.

Is there any problem with initialisation.

```
public Userlogin(String username, String brand, WebDriver driver) {
    WebElement user=driver.findElement(By.id("UserNameInputText")); 
    user.sendKeys(username);
    Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Brand")));
    select.selectByValue(brand);
    WebElement login_button=driver.findElement(By.id("CmdLogin"));
    login_button.submit();
    String actual_title=driver.getTitle();
    String expected_title="VSS 4";
    if(!(actual_title.matches(expected_title)))
    {
        Assert.assertFalse(false);
        driver.quit();
    }
    WebElement cancel=driver.findElement(By.id("Cancel"));
    if(!driver.findElements(By.id("Cancel")).isEmpty())
    {
                cancel.click(); 
    }
}
}
```

I am calling login in below code

```
package testcases;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import vsslogin.Userlogin;

public class messageboard extends Userlogin  {
 public messageboard(String username, String brand, WebDriver driver) {
    super(username, brand, driver);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
WebDriver driver;
@Test
 void messageboard() 
    {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Eclipse/chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://153.112.61.197/vss_connect_testr1/Login/Login.aspx?nextview=Welcome");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();    
    Userlogin login=new Userlogin("TYP40US","Mack",driver); 
    } 


    }
```

Comment: Have you got any exceptions/error output from the console/log?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `System.out.println()` statement in your code mentioned below and RUN.

If you have seen the "Close Browser" Message in Console. Tile of the Page is Not Matched with your expected_title.

Line : driver.quit();  is terminates your browser.

```
if(!(actual_title.matches(expected_title)))
{
    System.out.println("Close Browser");
    Assert.assertFalse(false);
    driver.quit();
}
```